# How can i debug (and hopefully fix) a websocket connection between an ionic 5 client and a NestJS server

Tags: sockets, ionic-framework, nestjs

I've been working many times with the MEAN stack but for this project I chose to upgrade it by using ionic 5 and NestJS and I now face new problems. First, for the Http communication i had to fix the CORS issue but thanks to this simple line it is now behind me.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

So after having my NestJS server talking to my Ionic app through Http I want them to have a socket connection to add a chat to my application. As far as i know my NestJs server is working well since i've been able to test it with this tool: https://socketserve.io/ the results are in the image below

images of the tool showing that the server is working

[image]

The problem is that when try to get the connection with my ionic client, the server get many unstable connection and the client receive no answer at all (the log of the connection show the chaotic connection pattern as show in the image below, these the logs for just one client trying to get a connection)

server logs

[image]

this is my code

server side:

```
import {
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer() server;
  users = 0;

  async handleConnection() {
    this.users++;
    console.log('connection, total: ' + this.users);
  }

  async handleDisconnect() {
    this.users--;
    console.log('disconnection, total: ' + this.users);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('event')
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string) {
    console.log(data);
    this.server.emit('event', 'anwser from server');
  }
}
```

the client app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {}};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    HttpClientModule],
  providers: [HttpClient, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the client page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authentification',
  templateUrl: './authentification.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authentification.page.scss'],
})
export class AuthentificationPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.connect();
    console.log('socket: ' + this.socket);
    this.socket.fromEvent('event').subscribe(data => {alert(data);});
  }

  socketTest() {
    this.socket.emit('event', 'from client');
    console.log('socket emited "event"');
  }

}
```

how to fix this? or/and if you could suggest me a tool to test my client socket like I test my server with SocketServe.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logs, and the knowledge that Nest is running socket.io v2.4.0 as of the latest version (version 7.x), it looks like your websocket client  (socket.io-client) version is either on v3.x or v4.x which is incompatible with server v2. You should downgrade the client to v2.4.0 or [use a custom adapter](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676#issuecomment-749719792) as described in the linked comment to make the server and client compatible again

Comment: thanks you for your help ! i tried both of the solutions but none of them work for me. When I downgrade my socket-io version on my client i have to exact same log as with the newest version. and when i try to use the custom adaptater i have the same error as DblK wich is still unsolve on the forum

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i got the socket working THANKS TO Jay !!! changing the verion was the wright anwser but i had to create a new ionic projet with a different angular version (11.x ) to be able to have the ngx-socket-io 3.3.1 version working wich is the last working with nestJs because for some reason that i dont understand in my first projet event i tried to change my socket version, it was automatically updated to 4.x causing the error